# In C#, when adding multiple service bus clients or administration clients to services, how can we get the correct one back from the service provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, client, azureservicebus

We have a microservice which needs to be able to send messages, not only to multiple Topics but to Topics which may live on different Azure Service Buses.

In other words, one Topic ("Foo") might need to be accessed by the connection string:
Endpoint=sb://foo.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=45346346346346346weffv34f43fc32c3d3d23=

and another ("Bar") might need to be accessed by the connection string:
Endpoint=sb://bar.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=sdvc243r4f4f32c3cd32c23dc2332c2332re=

I'm using the following model to get the connection strings out of the appsettings or Azure portal configuration:

```
public class MultiServiceBusSettings
{
    public List<string> ConnectionStrings { get; init; }

    private readonly Regex ConnectionStringPattern = new(@"(?:sb:\/\/)(.*)(?:\/)",
            RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
        );

    private Dictionary<string, string> _connectionStringsBySubdomain;

    private Dictionary<string, string> ConnectionStringsBySubdomain
    {
        get
        {
            if (_connectionStringsBySubdomain == null)
            {
                _connectionStringsBySubdomain = ConnectionStrings.ToDictionary(x =>
                {
                    Match match = ConnectionStringPattern.Match(x);
                    return match.Success
                        ? match.Groups[1].Value
                        : throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid connection string: {x}");

                });
            }

            return _connectionStringsBySubdomain;
        }
    }

    public string this[string subdomain] =>
        ConnectionStringsBySubdomain[subdomain];
}
```

And then using the following to add the clients to the solution:

```
        MultiServiceBusSettings settings = Configure<MultiServiceBusSettings>(services, configuration, configSectionName);
        services.AddAzureClients(builder =>
        {
            foreach (string connectionString in settings.ConnectionStrings)
            {
                _ = builder.AddServiceBusClient(connectionString);
                _ = builder.AddServiceBusAdministrationClient(connectionString);
            }
        }
        );
```

But now I need to modify the dependencies which will consume either the `ServiceBusClient` or `ServiceBusAdministrationClient`.

For example:

```
public class ServiceBusMessageSender : IMessageSender
{
    private readonly ServiceBusClient _serviceBusClient;

    public ServiceBusMessageSender(ServiceBusClient serviceBusClient) =>
        _serviceBusClient = serviceBusClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceBusClient));

    // Snipped for brevity
```

If I don't somehow tell the system which instance of `ServiceBusClient` to inject, I would expect the methods to at least occasionally fail.

What would be the best (or at least a good) way to fix this?

Comment: You can use named registrations to accomplish this:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/4162f6fa2445b2127468b9cfd080f01c9da88eba/sdk/extensions/Microsoft.Extensions.Azure/samples/Startup.cs#L39

You would then inject the IAzureClientFactory<ServiceBusClient> which would allow you to create the individual named clients:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/4162f6fa2445b2127468b9cfd080f01c9da88eba/sdk/extensions/Microsoft.Extensions.Azure/samples/Startup.cs#L71

Comment: @JoshLove, cheers for the response.  Since posting my question, I've already figured that out, but if you wish to make a proper answer, I'll be happy to accept it.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use named registrations to accomplish this, e.g https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/4162f6fa2445b2127468b9cfd080f01c9da88eba/sdk/extensions/Microsoft.Extensions.Azure/samples/Startup.cs#L39

You would then inject the IAzureClientFactory which would allow you to create the individual named clients: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/4162f6fa2445b2127468b9cfd080f01c9da88eba/sdk/extensions/Microsoft.Extensions.Azure/samples/Startup.cs#L71